# <picture> replacement of <img> is outside its enclosing <div>

Tags: html, css, image

I replaced an <img> tag with a <picture> tag and the image is now scaled to the width of the container, instead of the height, and it's below the containing div.

The picture tag can be seen here (the logo): https://notzeroyet.com/?ign_skip=4742231701016

If I use the markup editor in the browser and just replace the picture with the enclosed img, the logo displays just fine. Didn't notice any positional CSS (div > img or similar) that would impact.

Why would this happen?

Comment: remove `display: inline-block` from `#logo`

Comment: It's interesting to note that I tried to set `display: inline;` on the element but it's not working, only removing the rule from `#logo` works. I wonder why?

Comment: where did you set that `display: inline`? if you set it on `#logo` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> remove display: inline-block from #logo

Thanks @arieljuod, it worked.